# How to know how many times a method has been called from main class?

Tags: java

My problem is to find out how many times the `weight()` method is being called from the main class. I should calculate it in the `totalWeightsMeasured()` method.

The output of the code should be 0,2,6. (EDIT// I had earlier here 0,2,4 but the output should really be 0,2,6)

But I just don't have any idea how can you calculate it and I have tried to google and everything but I just don't know how to do it. (and **you are not supposed to add any more instance variables**)

#### CLASS:

```
public class Reformatory
{
    private int weight;



    public int weight(Person person)
    {
        int weight = person.getWeight();

        // return the weight of the person
        return weight;
    }
    public void feed(Person person)
    {
        //that increases the weight of its parameter by one.
        person.setWeight(person.getWeight() + 1);

    }
    public int totalWeightsMeasured()
    {


        return 0;
    }

}
```

#### MAIN:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Reformatory eastHelsinkiReformatory = new Reformatory();

        Person brian = new Person("Brian", 1, 110, 7);
        Person pekka = new Person("Pekka", 33, 176, 85);

        System.out.println("total weights measured "+eastHelsinkiReformatory.totalWeightsMeasured());

        eastHelsinkiReformatory.weight(brian);
        eastHelsinkiReformatory.weight(pekka);

        System.out.println("total weights measured "+eastHelsinkiReformatory.totalWeightsMeasured());

        eastHelsinkiReformatory.weight(brian);
        eastHelsinkiReformatory.weight(brian);
        eastHelsinkiReformatory.weight(brian);
        eastHelsinkiReformatory.weight(brian);

        System.out.println("total weights measured "+eastHelsinkiReformatory.totalWeightsMeasured());
    }
}
```

Comment: keep a counter, that increments with 1 each time it's called

Comment: _how many times the "weight()" method is being called_? keep a `static` counter variable, increment it in `weight()`.

Comment: add one custom function which will do print and make counter to 0.

Comment: @Stultuske Please, reread the line *you are not supposed to add any more instance variables*

Comment: @manetsus: where did I say it had to be an instance variable?

Comment: @manetsus a static variable is not an instance variable.

Comment: @Stultuske I think the user tried to mean something like: **you are not supposed to add any more variables for this purpose**, otherwise the problem is nothing!

Comment: @manetsus this looks like homework and the point is probably that they have to find out that a static variable is to be used here.

Comment: @manetsus: in that case, the answeris: not possible. I doubt that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @ParkerHalo yes, it could be. but I am thinking:  is it possible without using any variable?

Comment: @manetsus i was trying to think along the same lines but I've got nothing. The only possibilities I can think of is using a static counter variable or a static list that each weight is added to, the count is then the size of the list.

Comment: If you have an idea of Spring AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming), then AOP is best to use in your case.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to use a static counter variable. But, if you don't want to create a new instance variable, then Create a new class just having a single static counter variable and update it inside the weight method.

Comment: The desired output is 0,2,4, not 0,2,6? Then reset the static counter after each call to ``totalWeightsMeasured()``

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the existing instance variable weight, which is not used yet, as the counter.

```
public class Reformatory
{
    private int weight;

    public int weight(Person person)
    {
        int weight = person.getWeight();

        this.weight++;

        // return the weight of the person
        return weight;
    }
    public void feed(Person person)
    {
        //that increases the weight of its parameter by one.
        person.setWeight(person.getWeight() + 1);

    }
    public int totalWeightsMeasured()
    {
        return weight;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Satya, introduce a `static` counter variable as follows:

```
public class Reformatory {
    private static int weightMessurements = 0;

    public int weight(Person person) {
        // increment counter
        weightMessurements++;
        // messure weight
        return person.getWeight();
    }

    public void feed(Person person) {
        // increase weight
        person.setWeight(person.getWeight() + 1);
    }

    public int totalWeightsMeasured() {
        int result = weightMessurements;
        // reset counter so that the output matches 0,2,4 instead of 0,2,6
        weightMessurements = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP should note that a static variable is not the same as an instance variable. Static variables relate to the class itself rather than any particular instance of the class. I think that's worth mentioning since nobody has yet pointed out why this is the answer.

Comment: Hi! I tried this one but the output said that the exercise doesn't need static variables. So is there other way to do it without the static variables? (yes this is a homework and it is supposed to use some certain kind of code, but i dont have any idea)

Comment: @Chrale Logically viewed, the number of messurements needs to be kept track of somewhere, somehow. As it cannot be a local variable in the context of the Reformatory class, it could either be an instance or static member variable. If it's an instance variable, the number of messurements would relate to *that specific Reformatory*. If it's a static variable, the number would relate to *all Reformatories*, or not none (dependent on the usage). I found that ``private int weight;`` is not used in your code - could it possibly be that this is the reserved field for the counter?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution which will not require you to add any instance or static variables whatsoever.

Since inside this block of code you already have a **local** variable named `weight`.

```
public int weight(Person person) {
    int weight = person.getWeight();

    /return the weight of the person
    return weight;
}
```

Therefore, in the scope of that method you have **two** variables called `weight` but one is an **instance** variable and one is a **local** variable. You can differentiate between the two by writing `this.weight` for the instance variable, or just `weight` for the local variable.

All you need to do is to rename the current instance variable `weight` to `weightsMeasured` so that it clearer which variable you are referring to.

And then simply add `weightsMeasured++` into the `weight(Person person)` method and `return weightsMeasured` from the `totalWeightsMeasured()` method.

So the final code would look like this:

```
public class Reformatory
{
    private int weightsMeasured; //Renamed instance variable

    public int weight(Person person) {            
        weightsMeasured++; //instance variable incremented

        int weight = person.getWeight(); //This is the local variable           

        //return the weight of the person
        return weight;
    }

    public void feed(Person person) {
        //that increases the weight of its parameter by one.
        person.setWeight(person.getWeight() + 1);
    }

    public int totalWeightsMeasured() {
        //return the number of times the method was called
        return weightsMeasured; 
    }
}
```

So rather than adding any new variables, we just renamed the existing instance variable that wasn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified and shorter version of the above answers is:

```
public class Reformatory {

private int weight;

public int weight(Person  person) {

    this.weight++; //count the number of times when the weight gets measured.
    return person.getWeight();
}

public int totalWeightMeasured() {

    return weight; //return the number of times when the weight gets measured.
}
```

}